# How to remove all mutation from remote GraphQL schema?

Tags: graphql

I need to fetch remote graphql schema, keep there several specific queries (without mutations) and merge it with another schema. Everything works properly except mutation removal. I try this:

```js
  const filteredRemoteSchema = wrapSchema({
    schema: remoteSchema,
    transforms: [
      new FilterRootFields(
        (operation, rootField) => {
          if (operation === 'Query') {
            return QUERIES.includes(rootField);
          }
          if (operation === 'Mutation') {
            return false // It doesn't work
          }
          return true; 
        }
      ),
    ],
  });
```

I have an error:
Error: Type Mutation must define one or more fields.

It lets me keep one mutation but not zero. How can I remove all mutations from the remote schema?

Comment: Looks like no one knows or stackoverflow is already dead. I did work around - 
 let schemaString = printSchema(schema);
  schemaString = schemaString.replace(/type Mutation \{[^}]*\}/, '');
  const newRemoteSchema = buildSchema(schemaString);